# Why are the lines uneven?

Tags: pdftex, vertical-alignment, vietnamese

I have a piece of LaTeX code as follows. I have edited it in various ways but the spacing between the lines remains uneven.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\nonstopmode
\usepackage[right=2cm,left=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage{times}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\begin{document}  

    
    
    \begin{center}\Large\bfseries
        GIẤY CHỨNG NHẬN ĐẠT\\   
        THỰC HÀNH TỐT PHÂN PHỐI THUỐC\\ 
        GOOD DISTRIBUTION PRACTICES (GDP)\par
    \end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to add a screenshot of what you see at your end

Comment: With a baseline stretch of 1, the accents make the natural height of the first two lines bigger, so they are spaced more to avoid overlaps. With 1.3 they seem quite uniform to me (at least the baselines).

Comment: It's the stacked diacritics in your Vietnamese, to be sure. You'll probably want to increase spacing for all lines.

Comment: Off-topic: The keyword list `right=2cm,left=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm` may be expressed more succinctly as `margin=2cm`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to increase the value of `\baselinestretch` (as suggested in a comment by @Rmano), you could insert a `\vphantom{Ố}` directive -- a typographic strut, basically -- right before `\par`. Doing so assures that the vertical distance between lines 2 and 3 is the same as that between lines 1 and 2.

If you decide on increasing the interline spacing for the entire document by, say, 30%, don't set the low-level parameter `\baselinestretch` directly. Instead, do load the `setspace` package and issue the directive `\setstretch{1.3}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel} % optional
%\nonstopmode % why?
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage{times}
%%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1} % that's the default, no?

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{center}\Large\bfseries
        GIẤY CHỨNG NHẬN ĐẠT\\
        THỰC HÀNH TỐT PHÂN PHỐI THUỐC\\
        GOOD DISTRIBUTION PRACTICES (GDP)\vphantom{Ố}\par
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```